# Saving image in Excel workbook

Tags: image, excel, vba

I am building an Excel 2010 workbook that will use images to represent boards plugging into slots.  Currently, I am using LoadPicture to pull the image from the disk to use on the worksheet.  But when I send the workbook to somebody, they get error messages unless I send the image files also.  Is there a way to actually have the image files be a part of the workbook file so that I don't have to package the image files with the workbook?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you get the picture, make sure the picture is saved with the document and not just a link:

```
Sub GetThePicture()
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture _
        "c:\TestFolder\sample.jpg", _
            msoFalse, msoTrue, 100, 100, 70, 70
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, Gary's Student.  The size of the file went up, so I'm assuming the pictures are in there.  I just have to fool around with getting the ActiveX image control to see it.

Comment: Update this post if you require more assistance on this problem.